# Setting the thickness of an underline (text decoration) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underline, text-decorations

I am trying to find out how to set the thickness of an underline (the text decoration that happens when one hovers with the cursor) in JavaScript. Currently the text becomes underlined like this:

```
x.style.textDecoration = "underline";
```

and, "onmouseout", this is undone as follows:

```
x.style.textDecoration = "none";
```

All the advice I've seen online so far has to do with formatting the bottom borders of  tags. I am **not** trying to format a menu bar or any other element, but ordinary hyperlinks. I've tried it in various browsers, and the default underline looks fine in Firefox, but in Chrome, the line is hairline-thin, in contrast with the bold text it underlines.

Any advice on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be done easily using CSS?

Comment: I have to add a note here -- mobile devices don't *GET* a hover event or mouse-overs.  Mobile users need a clue that something is touchable/clickable.  Go, go ahead and make your underline aesthetic, just make it always there.

Answer (score 3):

CSS `:hover` should be used for such tasks

```
.x{
    /* default styles here */
}

.x:hover {
    /* HOVER default styles here */
}
```

if you want to be able to control the ***thickness*** of your "underline"
**use `border-bottom` instead** or **`box-shadow inset`**.

### Border on whole padded Anchor

```css
.x{
  display:         inline-block;
  color:           magenta;
  background:      #ddd;
  padding:         15px 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:   5px solid transparent;
  transition:      border-bottom 0.3s;
}

.x:hover{
  border-bottom-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<a class="x" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="x" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="x" href="#">Link 1</a>
```

### On Anchor's text only using inner `<span>` and  `inset box-shadow`

```css
.x{
  display:         inline-block;
  color:           magenta;
  background:      #ddd;
  padding:         15px 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.x span{
  transition:      0.3s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 trasparent;
}

.x:hover span{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 magenta;
}
```

```html
<a class="x" href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
<a class="x" href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
<a class="x" href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
```

### Using `:after` pseudo for more control

```css
.x{
  position:        relative;
  color:           magenta;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.x:hover:after{
  content:    "";
  position:   absolute;
  left:       0;
  bottom:     -3px;      /* Control bottom position */
  width:      100%;
  height:     5px;       /* Set your desired thickness */
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<a class="x" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="x" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="x" href="#">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: But border-bottom is not underlining : not at the same offset

Comment: @Kaiido *same offset* of what design exactly?

Comment: underline will draw a line on the baseline of the text. border-bottom will draw a line at the bottom of the box. Keep the default text-decoration, you'll see what I mean

Comment: @Kaiido if your design implies the use of a padded `a` tag than logically you'll wrap your text inside an inline `<span>` - and manipulate that span's border.

Comment: I'm not sure I got you, and I'm not sure you got me either. I'm not talking about padding, but about default offset. If you've got a solution to set the border-bottom at the same lineheight than the underline, then add it to your answer and I'd be glad to upvote your answer.

Comment: @Kaiido hope that the above will spice your imagination.

Comment: hum nope, you only add more padding while I'm talking about removing some :-) http://i.stack.imgur.com/l0DRP.png maybe box-shadow is the closest

Comment: @Kaiido you can control that using `a`'s line-height, and vertical-align, using inset box shadow or for perfect control an `:after` pseudo element.

Comment: Ok the `:after` solution is the one I would accept if I were OP. I'm not sure I'm convinced by "lineheight control" argument for border-bottom though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript to update the border-bottom style attribute, you can use:

```
someTag.style.borderBottom="3px solid blue";
```

Note that the CSS **border-bottom** is **borderBottom** in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try using `css` `:after` pseudo element , `:hover` , `font-family` set to `block` ; adjust `font-size` to change thickness of line, `top` to to change position of line corresponding to text of element

```css
div {
  width:24px;
}

div:after {
  position:absolute;
  top:-24px;
  content:"_";
  width:0px;
  color:#000;
  display:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:block;
  font-size:48px;
}

div:hover:after  {
   cursor:pointer;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
```